# Sharing legacy FormsAuthentication cookie in OWIN

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, forms-authentication

We have upgraded two ASP.NET MVC4 web apps to MVC5 and in order to use SignalR 2.x, we had to use `OWIN` in the updated app.
The two apps shared the same `machinekey` and `authentication` sections in web.config and if the user was logged in in app1, they were also automatically logged in in app 2:

```
<machineKey validationKey="<themachinekey>" decryptionKey="<thedecryptionKey>" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="2880" name=".ASPAUTH_VOCC" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Upon authenticating a user, both applications directly create authentication ticket/cookie the same way:

```
string userData = "ApplicationSpecific data for this user.";

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2,
    userName,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880),
    persistent,
    userData,
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

// Encrypt the ticket.
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
if (persistent)
{
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880);
}

// Create the cookie.
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I should also mention that in the update process, I did not make use of `app.UseCookieAuthentication` method in startup and prefered to stick with the above code for authentication.

While this approach worked fine on MVC4, after the update, both web apps act as if the authentication cookie from another app is not valid and while The user is authenticated in one app, they're still unauthenticated in the other app.

- Why is the authentication ticket not acceptable between the two apps anymore? My understanding is that I am sticking with legacy `FormsAuthentication` approach and decrypting the auth ticket from cookie should not have changed.
- Can I use `FormsAuthentication` in an OWIN-compatible web application and share the authentication cookie between my apps or should I make use of `OwinContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line in `web.config`'s `system.web` solved the problem:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Not sure what has been changed in FormsAuthentication encryption/decryption methods in .NET 4.5 compared to v4.0. After adding the above, the user is authenticated as expected in both apps.